# Simple way to add random string to template context

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a partial template that needs a random string every time its included. I need access the same random string than once per include and I'm not sure how many times the partial will be included.

I'm currently doing this to add it to the context

```
@register.tag
def randomgen(parser, token):
    return RandomgenNode()


class RandomgenNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context['randomgen_str'] = os.urandom(16).encode('hex')
        return ''
```

This lets me do `{% randomgen %}` at the beginning of the partial and `{{ randomgen_str }}` where I need the string. This isn't necessarily bad, I just didn't know if there was a preferred way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Adam, what do you mean by partial template?  As-in a template included through a template tag?  The main question is, does your template have access to the original context generated by your view?

Comment: Yes I meant that I just use the {% include %} tag to include it. I just meant like a "partial" template. That may not be the correct term. And yes I have access to original context, but I need a separate string for each time I include, with an unknown number of includes.

Comment: Can you take a look at the answer I've posted and let me know if it covers your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to garromark's I was able to find the best solution. Assignment tag did exactly what I wanted.

```
@register.assignment_tag
def randomgen():
    return os.urandom(16).encode('hex')
```

Then in my template I could use the following at the to of my included template

```
{% randomgen as randomgen_string %}
```

and use the following where I needed the random string

```
{{ randomgen_str }}
```

Comment: Now that I review, garromark's answer would have worked basically the same. Just using an custom include tag with context added or my way is just added to the context with a custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your included template were wrapped up into an inclusion tag, then you can modify the context before rendering the template.

For example, say presently you just do a simple template include for `template.html`:

```
{% include "templates/template.html" %}
```

This could be wrapped up into a template tag like:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("templates/template.html", takes_context=True)
def render_my_template(context):
    context['randomgen_str'] = os.urandom(16).encode('hex')
    return context
```

This will give you access to the original views context in `template.html` and will add in `randomgen_str` so you can access just like you have been.  Then instead of the `{% include %}` that was there before, you'd call `{% render_my_template %}`.

Comment: I'm not sure of the proper etiquette here. Your answer led me to my answer but I used something else. I'd just give you the answer but I don't want to confuse the next person searching.